# Where's the mistake?

Tags: functions

The graph of a function that solves equation $$(y')^3+27(y-1)^2=0$$ crosses through point $$A(-2;2)$$ and $$B(4;0)$$ Find the sum of the coordinates of its intersection point with the line $$3x-y-3=0$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiaxl.jpg)

Comment: The function does not crosses through two points at the same time

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Format your question using Mathjax.

Comment: @cpiegore I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think @the_candyman is quite correct. Curves with equations $(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} + x = c$ satisfy the equation for any $c$, as they say. But any portion of the line $y=1$ also satisfies the equation. Thus we have a continuous (in fact smooth) solution of the equation as $(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} + x = -1$, for $x \le -1$, $y=1$ for $-1 \le x \le 3$ and $(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} + x = 3$, for $x \ge 3$. This solution goes through (4, 0) and (-2, 2) as required. Desmos graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sb6rnqczfx.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from:

$$(y')^3+27(y-1)^2=0,$$

we easily get:

$$y' = \sqrt[3]{-27(y-1)^2} = -3(y-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}.$$

This can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -3(y-1)^{\frac{2}{3}} \Rightarrow (y-1)^{-\frac{2}{3}}dy = -3dx.$$

By integrating, we get the following general solution:

$$\int_{y(x_0)}^{y(x)}(y-1)^{-\frac{2}{3}}dy =-3\int_{x_0}^{x}ds \Rightarrow \\
\left.3(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right|_{y = y(x_0)}^{y = y(x)} =-3 \left(\left. s\right|_{s = x_0}^{s = x}\right) \Rightarrow \\
3(y(x)-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}- 3(y(x_0)-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} =-3(x - x_0) \Rightarrow \\
(y(x)-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}= (y(x_0)-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} -(x - x_0) \Rightarrow \\
y(x)= 1 + \left((y(x_0)-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} -(x - x_0)\right)^3 .$$

Suppose that $x_0 = -2$ and $y(x_0) = 2$ (that is, $A$ lies on $y(x)$). Then:

$$y(x)= 1 + \left((2-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} -(x +2)\right)^3  \Rightarrow \\
1 + (-x-1)^3 = 1 - (x+1)^3.$$

Now, let's check if the point $B = (4, 0)$ lies on $y(x)$. That is:

$$y(4) = 1 - (4+1)^3 = 1 - 125 = -124 \neq 4.$$

Hence, $B$ does not lie on $y(x)$.